# What does .= mean in PHP?

Tags: php

What is the difference between .= and = ? What is .= used for?

Example:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('WERK-tabelle.csv', 'r') or die('error');

$yml = '';
$keys = [
    blabla, code, php
];

while (($values = fgetcsv($file, 0, ';')) !== FALSE) {
    $yml .= "<br>";
    $arr = array_combine($keys, $values);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $yml .= "<br>{$key}{$value}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php?rq=1) for a more complete list of PHP operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.= is simply used to add something to the end of a string, without overwriting it.

Example 1 (without .=):

```
$myvar = "Hello";
$myvar = "Peter";
echo $myvar; //Will output "Peter"
```

Example 2 (With .=):

```
$myvar = "Hello";
$myvar .= "Peter";
echo $myvar; //Will output "HelloPeter" (concatenated string)
```

Comment: Big Thanks to @BenRoob for the edit. For sure, there will be no space between Hello and Peter.

Comment: Sorry for this hair splitting :)

Comment: @BenRoob Naaa its perfectly. I don't like not proper answers too and honestly its a quite big difference.

Comment: Does the .= automatically add a whitespace at the beginning of the next string?

Comment: @DenisFelst No.

Comment: @DenisFelst No, its exactly what Roob edited in my answer. I said that the output will be `Hello Peter` - whats not true. It will be `HelloPeter` without any whitespace. If you want the whitespace you have to do `$myvar .= " Peter";` or `$myvar = "Hello ";`

Comment: Fine, understood it the other way round. Thank all of you !!